# How data should be build in submitblock

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, solo-mining

I am trying to understand how bitcoin works internally in solo minning, and i am a little confused with the submitblock method:

```
version:     The current version
prev block:  The previous block
merkle root: The merkle root (Double SHA of the coinbase transaction)
timestamp:   The middle time
bits:        The difficulty
nonce        The valid nonce
num txs:     Number of the transaction (01 if it contains only coinbase transaction)
tx1:         The coinbase transaction (Built from the createrawtransaction method)
```

Is that correct?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I want add a fix at your post, the Merkle root is built with all transactions inside the block, so in other words the merkle tree is not a normal binary tree but it is built from the left. The merkle tree root is the result of some process that include all transactions

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo Yes, but if the block contains only the coinbase transaction, the merkle root will be only the double sha256 of the coinbase transaction (Little endian)? Or i am wrong?